# ASP.NET MVC Routing - subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

So my new web app, is dynamic web page and works based on the subdomain.
ie http://company1234.domain.com
I then take the parameter "company1234" and do a web api call to get the page information to display.

This all works very well.
However my issue is that if I need to call a parameter url ie http://company1234.domain.com/Home/GetClient?id=abcd
or
http://company1234.domain.com/Home/GetClientAccountDetails?model=abcd&acc=1234

All my routing is destroyed, cant figure out how I rework this?

```
public class SubdomainRoute : RouteBase
        {
            public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                if (httpContext.Request == null || httpContext.Request.Url == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var host = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
                var index = host.IndexOf(".");

                string[] segments = httpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.TrimStart('/').Split('/');

                if (index < 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var subdomain = host.Substring(0, index);

                string controller = (segments.Length > 0) ? segments[0] : "Home";
                string action = (segments.Length > 1) ? segments[1] : "Index";


                var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", action);
                routeData.Values.Add("subdomain", subdomain);



            return routeData;
            }

            public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
            {
                //Implement your formating Url formating here
                return null;
            }
        }
```

My Controller Methods

```
public ActionResult Index(string subdomain)
        {
//Go get custom page info
            var profile = GetProfile(subdomain);



            return View("Default", profile);
        }

public JsonResult GetClient(string id)
        {

//do stuff
}
```

My Global

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute());

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
            routes.MapRoute("Home",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Application", action = "Login" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}); 
        }
```

If I call
http://company1234.domain.com/Home/GetClient

Then this method is hit, however if i call
http://company1234.domain.com/Home/GetClient?id=1234
it does not work

Any ideas what I need to do to rework this and get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Routes need to do 2 things:

1. Determine if they match the request.
2. If they do, return a set of route values.

To handle the first requirement it is imperative that the route return `null` if it does not match the incoming request. This tells the routing framework to check the next registered route in the route table.

The problem is that your route does not check to ensure the URL that is passed is something it should handle, therefore it always matches the request and, since it is registered before all of your other routes, no other route can ever be reached. Normally, the `httpContext.Request.Path` is checked to ensure it matches some criteria, and if not, `null` should be returned.